# How to fix an element to viewport center regarding the container element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider two container elements side by side, both of them are longer than the width of the viewport and the viewport is scrollable horizontally. Both of them contain an element inside that I want to keep in the center of visible portion of the containing div. Here is the markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container" id="container1">
            <div class="element" id="element1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="container2">
            <div class="element" id="element2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is the css:

```
body {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 400%;
}
.container {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

I am very sorry I find it very difficult to describe what I need since English is not my native language but I would like to describe it with an image and an animation:

[[image: The effect I want to achieve in steps][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJr8.png)
[[image: The effect I want to achieve in animated gif form]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QduDT.gif)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your English is very good, but you need to show your attempt (markup). Please see the help pages.

Comment: Did you tried any code?

Comment: its difficult to understand what you want exactly
an horizontal animation or scroll ?

Comment: I think using mouse event and position of the container, with some mathematical operations we can assign a margin-left/left to the element inside of the container by limiting the margin or left value, which should not exceed some value. 
Note: Its an Idea only, but I think it will work.

Comment: I have added the markup and the poor css code (which is only to give the basic idea) I want div.element to stay in the center of the viewport as long as its parent (div.container) is visible at all. But when the visible portion of div.container is less than the width of viewport, then I want the element centered in this visible portion. It is really hard to explain, I am sorry again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want.

> **Gift:** check out the prettier [meoww version](https://jsfiddle.net/cho3n7z0/).

```js
$(".parallax").on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollValue = $(this).scrollLeft();
    var parallaxWidth = $(this).width();

    $(".box").each(function() {
        var container = $(this).parent();
        var containerWidth = $(container).width();
        var isLeftBox = $(container).is("#left");
        var ratioParallax = parallaxWidth/containerWidth;
        var ratioScroll = scrollValue/containerWidth;

        var move = 50*ratioParallax;

        if (isLeftBox) {
            move += ratioScroll*100;

            if (ratioScroll > 1/3)
                move -= (ratioScroll-1/3)*50;
        } else {
            move += (ratioScroll-1)*100;

            if (ratioScroll < 1)
                move -= (ratioScroll-1)*50;
        }

        $(this).css("left", move+"%");
    });
});

$(".parallax").trigger("scroll");
```

```css
div.parallax {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
}
div.parent-container {
    height:100%;
    width:300%;
}
div.container {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body div.container#left {
    background-color:red;
}
body div.container#right {
    background-color:blue;
}
div.box {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div id="left" class="container">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="container">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're describing is called parallax and can be a bit involved to accomplish exactly right.  Here's an example:  http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Have you tried any solutions yet?

Comment: I am familiar with parallax, unfortunately it is not solving my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple version with JavaScript. I don't if it works on every browser. I know for sure that it works on Safari and Firefox. It's very laggy, but it's possible fix that.

```js
var pageWidth;
var marginLeft1;
var marginLeft2 = margin;
var box1 = document.getElementById('box11');
var box2 = document.getElementById('box22');
var boxWidth = 200;
var largeBoxWidth = 2459;
var margin = 50;

function scrollY(Yscroll) {
 pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
 
 if(Yscroll + pageWidth < largeBoxWidth) {
  marginLeft1 = (pageWidth - boxWidth) / 2 + Yscroll;
 } else if(largeBoxWidth - Yscroll > 2*margin + boxWidth) {
  marginLeft1 = (pageWidth -  (Yscroll + pageWidth - largeBoxWidth)) / 2 + Yscroll - 0.5 * boxWidth;
 }
 
 if(Yscroll + pageWidth - largeBoxWidth < 2*margin + boxWidth) {
  marginLeft2 = margin;
 } else if(Yscroll + pageWidth <= largeBoxWidth) {
  marginLeft2 = (Yscroll + pageWidth - largeBoxWidth) / 2 - 0.5 * boxWidth;
 } else if(2*largeBoxWidth - Yscroll > pageWidth) {
  marginLeft2 = (Yscroll - largeBoxWidth) + 0.5*pageWidth - 0.5 * boxWidth;
 } else if(2*largeBoxWidth - Yscroll > 2*margin + boxWidth) {
  marginLeft2 = (Yscroll - largeBoxWidth) + (2*largeBoxWidth - Yscroll) / 2 - 0.5 * boxWidth;
 }
 
 
 if(Yscroll + pageWidth - largeBoxWidth > 2*margin + boxWidth && Yscroll - largeBoxWidth < 0) {
  marginLeft2 = (Yscroll + pageWidth - largeBoxWidth) / 2 - 0.5*boxWidth;
 }
 
 box2.style.marginLeft = marginLeft2 + 'px';
 box1.style.marginLeft = marginLeft1 + 'px';
}

scrollY(document.body.scrollLeft);
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#wrap {
 height:200px;
 width:6148px;
}

#box1 {
 width:40%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#FFDDDD;
 padding:50px 0;
 display:inline-block;
}

#box11 {
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#FF0000;
}


#box2 {
 width:40%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#DDFFDD;
 padding:50px 0;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:-4px;
}

#box22 {
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll='scrollY(document.body.scrollLeft)'>
  <div id='wrap'>
    <div id='box1'>
      <div id='box11'></div>   
    </div>
  
    <div id='box2'>
      <div id='box22'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```